# Mapping All Terminal IDs to Previous IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that contains a list of all ID migrations overtime. An individual's ID can change overtime, and this table helps us understand when the change occurs, and what the ID changes from/to. What I'd ultimately like is a way to list all of the previous IDs for the most recent ID (which I'm referring to as the terminal ID). I'm assuming this will require some sort of CTE, but my brain is in a bit of a fog as to how I should set this up.

```
CREATE TABLE #ExampleIdCrosswalk
(
    CurrentId VARCHAR(3)
    ,PreviousId VARCHAR(3)
    ,PreviousIdObsoleteDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #ExampleIdCrosswalk
VALUES 
('DEF','ABC','2021-01-01')
,('WVU','ZYX','2021-01-01')
,('MNO','ONM','2021-02-01')
,('PPP','EEE','2021-02-01')
,('GHI','DEF','2021-03-01')
,('TSR','WVU','2021-03-01')
,('NRP','QRS','2021-03-01')
,('JKL','GHI','2021-04-01')


SELECT * FROM #ExampleIdCrosswalk
```

Ultimately, what I'd like to show is a table with all the terminal ID's along with each of their corresponding previous IDs.

[image: Example]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
      select currentid, previousid
      from ExampleIdCrosswalk ec
      where not exists (select 1 from ExampleIdCrosswalk ec2 where ec2.previousId = ec.currentid)
      union all
      select cte.currentid, ec.previousid
      from cte join
           ExampleIdCrosswalk ec
           on ec.currentId = cte.previousId
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3648f95297d9638d763cf61b949d33b1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, you used one column less. As a side note I'm trying to convince myself of using `*` instead of `1` for the `EXIST` clause. For some reason `1` looks better, but I keep on thinking `*` makes more sense.

Comment: The column(s) being selected are immaterial.  I prefer `1` because it is easiest to type.  `*` always gives me a pause, because I think "do I really need all of them" -- even though there is no performance impact.  Postgres has a particularly ugly syntax where you can leave the column out -- just `select` without nothing else.  It is rather ghostly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE, as in:

```
with
n (last, curr, prev) as (
  select currentid, currentid, previousid
  from ExampleIdCrosswalk where currentid not in (
    select previousid from ExampleIdCrosswalk
  )
 union all
  select n.last, c.currentid, c.previousid
  from n
  join ExampleIdCrosswalk c on c.currentid = n.prev
)
select last, prev
from n
order by last, prev
```

Result:

```
 last  prev 
 ----- ---- 
 JKL   ABC  
 JKL   DEF  
 JKL   GHI  
 MNO   ONM  
 NRP   QRS  
 PPP   EEE  
 TSR   WVU  
 TSR   ZYX
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da543b2fec2d2b2efb4d857ba9f5306b).